# Why am I getting a segmentation fault while reading a CSV of integers?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here are the contents of the `test.csv`,

```
95,47
460,215
```

I wrote this C program to read it into an array of long longs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 2

void read(char path[], long long (*B)[DIM]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  long long B[DIM][DIM];
  read("test.csv", B);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
      printf("%lld\n", B[i][j]);
  return 0;
}

void read(char path[], long long (*B)[DIM]) {
  int i, j;
  int c, sign = 1;
  long long number = 0;
  FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
  if (fp) {
    while ((c = getc(fp)))
      if (c == '-') {
        sign = -1;
      } else if (c == ',') {
        B[i][j++] = sign * number;
        sign = 1;
        number = 0;
      } else if (c == '\n') {
        B[i++][j] = sign * number;
        j = 0;
        sign = 1;
        number = 0;
      } else if (c == EOF) {
        B[i][j] = sign * number;
        break;
      } else if ('0' >= c || c <= '9') {
        number = (number * 10) + (c - '0');
      }
    fclose(fp);
  } else {
    printf("File %s not found.\n", path);
  }
}
```

My C is a bit rusty and this gets me a segmentation fault.  I don't see why? Funnily enough, if I comment the 2D loop in main then the program runs fine.

Comment: Where do you get a segmentation fault? If you run your program in a debugger, you should see where it happens. Then you can inspect the variables that were involved. Do they contain what you expect?

Comment: On this line `B[i++][j] = sign * number;` `i`, and `j` are not initialized. The initial values of  `i` and `j` are undermined. There may be more problems though.

Comment: Oh... right. But why does the program run then if I comment out the loop in main?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can be anything. It can also seem to work properly.

Comment: @scribe probably because of untertemined behaviour. Uninitialized variable do not necessarily crash the program. Google "c undefined behaviour"

Comment: Also it should be `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)`. Read the documentation of `getc`.

Comment: compiler here says that at line 35 you are using an unitialized value... If you care about a `-` why not accept `+` also? Why not use conversion functions like `atol()` from `stdlib`? Or `scanf()` that could also convert all values at once?

Comment: @Jabberwocky It should not be comparing with EOF in the while loop condition since then it will instantly break the loop without ever assigning the number in the last row and the last column.

Comment: @arfneto The function will always be reading the CSV I have generated and I know that the "+" cases will not happen.   Also, I am not very C savvy so I am not sure how one could use those functions.   The one nice thing about my implementation is that it does not rely on knowing the dimensions of the CSV ahead of time.

Comment: @arfneto my compiler `gcc` did not say that.

Comment: `long long B[DIM][DIM]` this is the area you are passing to `read()`. It is fixed size, `static`. As soon as your program reaches the 3rd `\n´`of an input file your program will crash, so you need to know the dimensions in terms of lines. And also in terms of columns, since it will also crash with a 3rd column. as for `gcc` I have no idea of what you writing about

Comment: IDK what are you talking about.  It does not crash with the `i, j` initialised as pointed out in the answer.  I'll let you figure out why.

Comment: if you updated the code you must update it here. It is clear that in the very first line in `read`  these variables are not initialized and your compiler told you that. And inside the loop you use `i` and  `j` to access `B[i][j++]`

Comment: even correcting the initial problems it will still crash in many cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always initialize variables before using them:

```c
void read(char path[], long long (*B)[DIM]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;    // i and j should be initialized to zero
  // ...
}
```